# How can I convert several NumPy arrays with ints to a NumPy array with formatted strings?

Tags: python, arrays, string, numpy, formatting

I have three arrays of the same length containing integers: `years`, `months` and `days`.  I want to create a (NumPy) array of the same length, containing formatted strings like `'(-)yyyy-mm-dd'` using the format `'%i-%2.2i-%2.2i'`.

For the scalar case, I would do something like

```py
year=2000; month=1; day=1
datestr = '%i-%2.2i-%2.2i' % (year, month, day)
```

which would yield `'2000-01-01'`.

How can I create the vector version of this, e.g.:

```py
import numpy as np
years  = np.array([-1000, 0, 1000, 2000])
months = np.array([1, 2, 3, 5])
days   = np.array([1, 11, 21, 31])
datestr_array = numpy.somefunction(years, months, days, format='%i-%2.2i-%2.2i', ???)
```

Note that the date range I am interested in lies between the years -2000 and +3000 (CE), and hence both Python's `datetime` and Pandas' `DateTimeIndex` offer no solution.

Comment: `datastr_array = ['%i-%2.2i-%2.2i'.format(years[j], months[j], days[j]) for j in range(len(years))]` - while this may look complicated, it is literally just formatting however many times are necessary.

Comment: @LarrytheLlama Thank you for your quick reply.  But this looks like a for loop.  If I understand correctly, the point of NumPy is to avoid for loops and use the faster compiled C code.

Comment: First, the way you defined years, months and days, they are not numpy arrays, but lists. If you have numpy arrays, maybe you could try numpy.array2string https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.array2string.html

Comment: @RobertoT Thanks, I threw in a few np.array()'s for clarity.  I looked at `numpy.array2string()`, but the examples seem to suggest that all numbers must have the same format and you get a string containing an array, not an array of strings.  Can you give an example of how I can feed my format string to `numpy.array2string()` to get an array of formatted strings with integers of different lengths?

Comment: You are right, I thought maybe it was a possible way but looks like always returning a string copy of the array.

Comment: Fast compiled code mostly works for numeric stuff, not strings

Comment: @hpaulj OK, so I shouldn't worry about for loops here.  Thanks!

Comment: @LarrytheLlama Could you check your `diststr_array` code above?  I get an array of literal `'%i-%2.2i-%2.2i'` rather than numbers and I'm not sure what's wrong...

Comment: Dw @AstroFloyd - look at the code below - it fixes everything

Comment: Such a feature is [not yet implemented for the datetime type](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/17083) already, so obviously not for multiple arrays (there is no generic formatting function in Numpy yet). I wonder if there is some tricks that can be used to get similar results manually without a loops but the string handling in Numpy is very limited, so I thing the best way may be to use a loop or maybe a C/Cython module (generating a Numpy array since it will not be faster with pure Python strings).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple list comprehension will be faster than `numpy` functions:

```
['%i-%2.2i-%2.2i'%(y,m,d) for y,m,d in zip(years, months,days)]
```

for a dataframe

```
arr = df[['year','month','day']].values   # a (n,3) array
['%i-%2.2i-%2.2i'%(y,m,d) for y,m,d in arr]
```

Adding an `arr=arr.tolist()` might add some speed, since iteration of an list is faster than on an array.

Answer (score 2):

## Explanation

Let's create a function that will convert *any* date without bounds to a *yyyy-mm-dd* string. We can use string formatting, where we create a predefined string and simply format in the relevant data. We also need to format the length to have zeros at the front to 'fill it out', i.e. *2001-05-20*.

To be able to run this function, all the respective years months and days must be grouped together, which can be achieved with a `zip` function, which groups rows between columns as tuples. Preferably, we will convert this to a `numpy` array.

Now that we have the data in the correct tupled form, let's parse it through our function. We can create a new array that does this using `apply`, namely `numpy.apply_on_axis(func, axis, data)`. Because the tuples are in the second axis, the axis parameter must be set to 1.

## Code

```
def FormatDate(data):
    # Where data is a tuple for y, m, d
    return "{0:04}-{1:02}-{2:02}".format(data[0], data[1], data[2]) # Note that this formatting can later be update to account for some weirdness

# Convert the data into tuples where y, m, d are aligned in rows
converted = numpy.array(list(zip(years, months, days)))

# Now, lets apply that function to make the tuples all dates
datestr_array = numpy.apply_along_axis(FormatDate, 1, converted)
```

Comment: If you would like an explanation, just add a comment.

Comment: Thanks Larry.  However, Python's `datetime` gives me a `ValueError: year -1000 is out of range`.  I think `datetime` doesn't believe the world existed before the year 1 CE, and `DateTimeIndex` doesn't even believe in the Middle Ages...

Comment: @AstroFloyd Edited- It can handle extreme dates AND Negatives.. EDIT: the hyphens may be a little confusing - you can change that by just editing the existing ones with `.`'s, etc. - Such as `"{0:04}.{1:02}.{2:02}"`

Comment: @LarrytheLlama great solution but I think yo should change the axis: 0 to 1 in \datestr_array = numpy.apply_along_axis(FormatDate, 0, converted)\ . Then it will work great!

Comment: Yes, thanks - I did that with my code but forgot to edit the post @RobertoT

Comment: @LarrytheLlama Could you explain what does your function? - the return line. I'm thrilled now.

Comment: Thank you so much Larry and @RobertoT for the great interplay!  :-)

Comment: @RobertoT The return line takes argument 0 from `.format()` zero-padded and with length 4, then args  1 and 2, zero padded and with length 2.  I need to catch up on my `{}` vs. `%` placeholders.

Comment: `apply_along_axis` adds nothing to this, not even speed.  The simple list comprehension is faster, `['%i-%2.2i-%2.2i'%(y,m,d) for y,m,d in zip(years, months,days)]`.  This is the same `zip` used to create `conveted`.

Comment: @hpaulj What if I have the Pandas DataFrame `df[['year','month','day']]` instead of `zip(years, months, days)`?

Comment: `df[['year','month','day']].values` will be an array like `converted`.  `pandas` may have some str functionality that makes this easier.  It uses python strings in object dtype Series.  I've seen people use some sort of `df.str` code, but haven't done anything myself.

Comment: @hpaulj Indeed, this is easier, shorter and more flexible.  Do you want to turn it into an answer?